# How to use Google Map API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to use the google Maps API v3. Where can i get the information for using the Google Maps in my application through the javascript without the API Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API key is no longer necessary with v3.

You can insert a reference to the API like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
       src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
```

Comment: Actually in my present application i am using GMap2 so how can i change it to the version 3 without using the API Key? can u please explain in breif?

Comment: Thanks for ur response, can u please explain it in breif?

Comment: @saturngod's links are great places to start.

Comment: i placed the above script where i replaced the api script tag. but the map is not visible if i am using the above script which yioou have given.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn from

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

If you want to test or see demo, try in

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3

Comment: How to get latitude and longitude values for the given address?